# Temporarily disable a Toyota Aqua?

Tags: toyota, hybrid, security

Is there a way to sort of "Disable" a Toyota Aqua, in such a way that it won't start, but can easily be re-enabled? e.g. by removing a part that can easily be put back in?

The idea here is a stop-gap measure to prevent theft as it seems there is a surge of Toyota Aqua thefts in my area - I have read they are easy to steal which is why they are targeted, and until I can get a more permanent security solution, I'd like to make it not so easy, so something I could do last thing at night then undo first thing in the morning is what I'm looking for.

Previously, in a full petrol-engine car I was able to easily unscrew a small wire connected to the battery to which made it impossible to start, but that car was old and on the way out, and I wasn't extremely bothered about the risk of permanent damage, plus, I know a lot less about hybrid engines (the battery is presumably more integral to the car so damage to it would be a much bigger deal)

Comment: At first blush I'd suggest to remove a fuse, specifically #12 in the under hood fuse block. This fuse controls the multi-point fuel injection on the car. There's an issue and a concern with doing this. Issue: it also controls a lot of other stuff, including the key fob. Disabling this fuse might not allow you to easily get into your car. Concern: Pulling this fuse will disable the ICE, but will the car still function on battery power alone? If it does, pulling this fuse won't do you any good. Pulling the fuel injection fuse is how I'd disable a non-hybrid vehicle.

Comment: A wheel clamp is pretty quick to fit and remove, or a bar-type steering wheel clamp.

Comment: I don't know about the Toyota Aqua, but on a Toyota Prius, there is a hybrid battery 'lockout' connector. It is bright orange and located under the cargo floor that you would remove to get to the spare tire. Removing this should disable the car.

Comment: @GlenYates will the Prius still run on the fossil engine?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not positive, I just replaced the head gasket on one this weekend, and I know it complained when we were first trying to start it back up because I hadn't pushed the lock back into place properly. But while you're under the rear cargo floor, disconnect the negative 12v battery cable as well, then it won't start/run for sure.

Comment: Do you have any information on how Aqua's are defeated for stealing? If you have this info, you may be able to determine a shutoff circuit to disable theft. With electric hybrids, there may be some complications with something as simple as interrupting the START switch circuit to something more complex requiring wiring diagrams. In theory, wiring in a simple on/off switch spliced into a key circuit may be all that's needed to discourage theft if a thief can't/won't spend time determining a defeat circuit hidden in wiring yet accessible to you.